# How to determine scale factor in android

Tags: android, imageview, zooming

How to determine scale factor after zoom. I am using below code for pinch zoom. After zoom I have to draw circle on bitmap at correct location. I heard this the formula we have to use to draw at correct point after zoom.

Formula:

```
 float x = ev.getX() / mScaleFactor + rect.left;  
 float y = ev.getY() / mScaleFactor + rect.top;
```

I have no idea how to calculate mScaleFactor.

I am using below code for pinch zoom,

```
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent rawEvent) {
  WrapMotionEvent event = WrapMotionEvent.wrap(rawEvent);
  // ...
  ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

  // Dump touch event to log
  dumpEvent(event);

  // Handle touch events here...
  switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
     savedMatrix.set(matrix);
     start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
     Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
     mode = DRAG;
     break;
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
     oldDist = spacing(event);
     Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
     if (oldDist > 10f) {
        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
        midPoint(mid, event);
        mode = ZOOM;
        Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
     }
     break;
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
     mode = NONE;
     Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
     break;
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
     if (mode == DRAG) {
        // ...
        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
        matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x,
              event.getY() - start.y);
     }
     else if (mode == ZOOM) {
        float newDist = spacing(event);
        Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
        if (newDist > 10f) {
           matrix.set(savedMatrix);
           float scale = newDist / oldDist;
           matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
        }
     }
     break;
  }

  view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
  return true; // indicate event was handled
```

}

I am using imageview for displaying the image and zoom.
Using canvas and bitmap I am drawing the circle and setting to the image view after draw.

How to calculate scale factor for above pinch zoom code ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

f you use the ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener class you can do something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector){ 
   //the focal point before taking into account the zoom/translations/etc  
   float startX = detector.getFocusX();
   float startY = detector.getFocusY();

   initialPoints = new float[]{startX, startY};
    if(transformMatrix.invert(inverseTransformMatrix))
        inverseTransformMatrix.mapPoints(initialPoints );
  //initialPoints now contain the correct points based on the current zoom
}
```